# :hover not fired for element when parent has CSS3 perspective

Tags: html, css, hover, transform

In the following example I created on jsfiddle try to hover on gray boxes. You can see each "Box" inside the first container gets ":hover" but for the second one items located on "the right half of the container" don't get :hover!

(move your mouse over gray boxes)
(Open this in Chrome or Safari because other browsers don't support CSS3 perspective)
Look at here: http://jsfiddle.net/jyBES/10/

This is very strange to me.

Can anybody explain why? Is there any possible workaround for this?

Comment: In firefox 6 I can't see the difference between the two.

Comment: @Oliver: If you bothered to read the code in the fiddle, you'll realize that you need to test this in a WebKit browser.

Comment: because FF6.0 doesn't support perspective! try chrome or safari

Comment: Actually, it looks like this is an issue with `rotateY()` rather than with `perspective()`. If you remove the `perspective()`, you'll have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float: left;
```

in the parent div seems to do the job.

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/jyBES/11/

Comment: And why is that? ;) (I have a similar problem with absolutely positioned children and I wonder if this is the only solution)

Comment: @jpc I honestly have no idea. Floating elements is a pretty solid way of telling the element to wrap the content/child elements tightly into a warm and fuzzy wrap, so I gave it a shot in this instance, and it did the job.